# Facing issue while exporting data from Vertica to S3 using s3export

Tags: amazon-s3, vertica

I am exporting data from Vertica to S3 using s3export. It is giving below exception:

> `[Vertica][VJDBC](5861) ERROR: Error calling processPartition() in
>   User Function s3export at [src/S3.cpp:471], error code: 0, message:
>   Client Error: The request signature we calculated does not match the
>   signature you provided. Check your key and signing method`.

how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you find any answer?

Comment: can you post your sample code?

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of the incorrect AWS credentials provided. Alter the vertica session to include the aws credentials for awslib. Something as -

```
ALTER SESSION SET UDPARAMETER FOR awslib aws_id='*****'

ALTER SESSION SET UDPARAMETER FOR awslib aws_secret='*****'

ALTER SESSION SET UDPARAMETER FOR awslib aws_session_token='****' (If using temp credentials)
```